# alpha property problem in swf file

Tags: actionscript-3

i made a button & i used a on click event on this. So it can show some images. but after that when i click on another button for showing some text the images still upon there. Images hide the text. what will be the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is you see images and you don't want to see them? Then the blindingly obvious solution is to remove the images. You didn't give any details on how you add the images, so can't give specific advice on how to remove them.